# QuickSort with Pivot Function issue?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have been looking at this for the past couple hours and can still not understand where I have messed up. I keep getting Index out of bounds errors like below:

[image]

Each small edit or change i have done, has run me into another error, then i end back up here after trying to simplify my code.

```
def quickSort(alist):
    firstList = []
    secondList = []
    thirdList = []

    if(len(alist) > 1):
        #pivot = pivot_leftmost(alist)
        #pivot = pivot_best_of_three(alist)
        pivot = pivot_ninther(alist)
        #pivot = pivot_random(alist)

        for item in alist:
            if(item < pivot):
                firstList.append(item)
            if(item == pivot):
                secondList.append(item)
            if(item > pivot):
                thirdList.append(item)
        sortedList = quickSort(firstList) + secondList + quickSort(thirdList)
        return sortedList
    else:
        print("list:", alist)
        print("sorted, nothing to do") #debug
        print("") #debug
        return alist

def pivot_ninther(alist):
    listLength = int(len(alist))
    third = int(listLength / 3)

    leftList = alist[:third]
    midlist = alist[third:(third * 2)]
    lastlist = alist[(third * 2):(third * 3)]

    leftBest = pivot_best_of_three(leftList)
    midBest = pivot_best_of_three(midlist)
    lastBest = pivot_best_of_three(lastlist)

    pivots = [leftBest, midBest, lastBest]

    return pivot_best_of_three(pivots)
```

I am pretty sure a fresh pair of eyes can easily find it, but i have been lookig at it for hours. Thanks!

UPDATE: (My Best_of_three function)

```
def pivot_best_of_three(alist):
    leftmost = 0
    middle = int(len(alist) / 2)
    rightmost = len(alist) - 1

    if (alist[leftmost] <= alist[middle] <= alist[rightmost] or alist[rightmost] <= alist[middle] <= alist[leftmost]):
        return alist[middle]
    elif (alist[middle] <= alist[leftmost] <= alist[rightmost] or alist[rightmost] <= alist[leftmost] <= alist[middle]):
        return alist[leftmost]
    else:
        return alist[rightmost]
```

Comment: The code in your error message isn't present in the main code block. Is it from the `pivot_best_of_three` function?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes it is. I just posted that code to the question. Sorry.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am pretty sure each method works exactly as they are supposed to, however when i use them together, something is going wrong.

Comment: I'll post some code in a minute, but the problem is caused by `pivot_ninther` passing lists of length zero to `pivot_best_of_three`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IndexError` occurs when `pivot_best_of_three` tries to find the `rightmost` member of a list of zero items. The simple way to fix that is to simply not pass it such lists. :)

Here are slightly modified versions of those functions. I've tested these versions with lists of various lengths, down to length zero, and they appear to function correctly.

```
def pivot_ninther(alist):
    listLength = len(alist)
    if listLength < 3:
        return alist[0]

    third = listLength // 3
    leftList = alist[:third]
    midlist = alist[third:-third]
    lastlist = alist[-third:]

    leftBest = pivot_best_of_three(leftList)
    midBest = pivot_best_of_three(midlist)
    lastBest = pivot_best_of_three(lastlist)

    pivots = [leftBest, midBest, lastBest]

    return pivot_best_of_three(pivots)

def pivot_best_of_three(alist):
    leftmost = alist[0]
    middle = alist[len(alist) // 2]
    rightmost = alist[-1]

    if (leftmost <= middle <= rightmost) or (rightmost <= middle <= leftmost):
        return middle
    elif (middle <= leftmost <= rightmost) or (rightmost <= leftmost <= middle):
        return leftmost
    else:
        return rightmost
```

As you can see, I've simplified `pivot_best_of_three` so it doesn't index `alist` multiple times for the same value.

But it can be simplified further by using a simple [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network):

```
def sort3(a, b, c):
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    if b < a: a, b = b, a
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    return a, b, c

def pivot_best_of_three(alist):
    leftmost = alist[0]
    middle = alist[len(alist) // 2]
    rightmost = alist[-1]
    return sort3(leftmost, middle, rightmost)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a smaller count (<= 20) and check to see what happens in pivot_ninther() when third == 0 (at the deepest level of recursion)? Seems like it would create empty arrays and then try to index them.

The code should check to make sure length >= 9 before calling pivot_ninther(), then >= 3 if calling ...best_of_three(). If just one or two items, pick one.

Suggestion, after you get the quicksort to work, back up the source code and rather than make new arrays, the pivot function should work with the original array and first / middle / last indexes.

You can use swaps to simplify finding the median of 3. This will help in cases like starting with a reversed order array.

```
    // median of 3
    i = lo, j = (lo + hi)/2, k = hi;
    if (a[k] < a[i])
        swap(a[k], a[i]);
    if (a[j] < a[i])
        swap(a[j], a[i]);
    if (a[k] < a[j])
        swap(a[k], a[j]);
    pivot = a[j];
```

wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot

Comment: I would prefer to use list slicing (but your way would be more efficient). How is my implementation wrong?

Comment: So my quicksort is incorrect, or the ninther method?

Comment: If i only have two items in a list, I would still need to pick a pivot point correct? I just would do it inside the best of three?